# Xquery transformation issue in OSB

Tags: xml, xquery

I have created XQuery with user defined function. Everything work fines as expected, but when i add a test condition(if ($CountFirstName > 0) "if-then-else" logic on the tag OrderItem, i am getting error "{err}XP0003: Invalid expression: expecting ''" in my OSB I am not sure what went wrong in syntax, can some one pls help me rectifying the code.

**

- Xquery

**

```
declare namespace ns2   = "http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YCP/getPage/output";
declare namespace ns1   = "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9";
declare namespace ns4   = "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/commerce/9/order";
declare namespace ns3   = "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/commerce/9/foundation";
declare namespace ns0   = "http://WCToSSFSMediationModule";
declare namespace xf    = "http://tempuri.org/POC_HttpMethodCall/XQueries/getPageRequestoShowOrder/";
declare namespace _ord  = "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/commerce/9/order";
declare namespace _wcf  ="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/commerce/9/foundation";



declare function local:getfor-eachLoop($valueMaps as element() * , $Order as element()*) as element() *
{

  let $scStatus := data($Order/@MaxOrderStatus),
  $status   := $valueMaps/*:ValueMaps/*:Map[@name='scStatusToWcStatus']/*:Entry[@key=$scStatus]/text(),
  $statusF  :=        if (data($Order/@MultipleStatusesExist) = 'Y') then 'S' else  $status,
  $scCurrency := data($Order/*:PriceInfo/@Currency),
  $wcCurrency := $valueMaps/*:ValueMaps/*:Map[@name='scCurrencyToWcCurency']/*:Entry[text()=$scCurrency]/@key,
  $currency   := if(fn:string-length(normalize-space($wcCurrency)) > 0) then $wcCurrency    else $scCurrency    , 
  $FirstName :=  data($Order/*:PersonInfoShipTo/@FirstName),
  $LastName :=  data($Order/*:PersonInfoShipTo/@LastName),
  $CountFirstName :=fn:string-length(normalize-space($FirstName))
  return
          (
            <_ord:Order>
                    <_ord:OrderIdentifier>
                           <_wcf:UniqueID>{data($Order/@OrderNo)}</_wcf:UniqueID>
                           <_wcf:ExternalOrderID>{data($Order/@OrderHeaderKey)}</_wcf:ExternalOrderID>
            </_ord:OrderIdentifier>
                    <_ord:OrderAmount>
                        <_wcf:GrandTotal  currency = "{$currency}">{data($Order/*:OverallTotals/@GrandTotal)}</_wcf:GrandTotal>   
             </_ord:OrderAmount>

                      <_ord:OrderStatus>
                       <_ord:Status>{$statusF}</_ord:Status>
            </_ord:OrderStatus>
                       <_ord:PlacedDate>{data($Order/@OrderDate)}</_ord:PlacedDate>


                   if ($CountFirstName > 0) then
                     <_ord:OrderItem>
                               <_ord:OrderItemShippingInfo>
                                     <_ord:ShippingAddress>
                                          <_wcf:ContactName>
                                          <_wcf:FirstName>
                                                     {$CountFirstName}
                                           </_wcf:FirstName>
                                          </_wcf:ContactName>
                                      </_ord:ShippingAddress>
                                </_ord:OrderItemShippingInfo>
                       </_ord:OrderItem>
                    else ()
                                   </_ord:Order>           
           )



};

declare function xf:getPageRequestoShowOrder($valueMaps as element() * , $getPageRequest as element()*) as element() *
{

let $OrganizationCode :=  data($getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/*:Order/@EnterpriseCode),
$storeId          :=  data($valueMaps/*:Map[@name='storeIdToOrganizationCode']/*:Entry[@key=$OrganizationCode]),
$recordSetCount   := if (data($getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/@TotalOrderList) > 0 ) then data($getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/@TotalOrderList) else 0,
$recordSetTotal   := if (data($getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/@TotalNumberOfRecords) > 0) then data($getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/@TotalNumberOfRecords) else 0,
$RCmpltInd       := if (data($getPageRequest/@IsLastPage) = 'Y') then 'true' else 'false',

$xml :=
<ns4:ShowOrder>
    <ns1:ApplicationArea>
        <ns1:CreationDateTime>{fn:current-dateTime()}</ns1:CreationDateTime>
    </ns1:ApplicationArea>
    <ns4:DataArea>
        <ns1:Show recordSetCount = "{$recordSetCount}"  recordSetTotal = "{$recordSetTotal}" recordSetCompleteIndicator = "{$RCmpltInd}" />

        {
         for $Order in $getPageRequest/*:Output/*:OrderList/*:Order
         return
            local:getfor-eachLoop($valueMaps,$Order)
        }
    </ns4:DataArea>
</ns4:ShowOrder>

return $xml
};


declare variable $valueMaps as element(ns0:ValueMaps) external;
declare variable $getPageRequest as element(ns2:Page) external; 

 xf:getPageRequestoShowOrder($valueMaps,$getPageRequest)  


(:
let $valueMaps        :=   fn:doc(ValueMaps.xml') 
let $getPageRequest   :=   fn:doc(getPageresponeNS.xml') 

let $x := xf:getPageRequestoShowOrder($valueMaps/*:ValueMaps,$getPageRequest/*:Page)  

return $x
:)
```

**

- ValueMaps XML

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 =================================================================
  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM

  WebSphere Commerce

  (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011 All Rights Reserved.

  US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
  disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with
  IBM Corp.
 =================================================================
-->

<!-- Maps WC values to SSFS values -->
<mm:ValueMaps
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mm="http://WCToSSFSMediationModule"
>


    <mm:Map name="scStatusToWcStatusGroup">
        <mm:Entry key="1100">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="1300">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="1310">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="1400">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="1500">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3200">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3200.10000">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3200.20000">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3350">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3700">shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3700.01">returned</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="3700.02">returned</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="9000">cancelled</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="M">not shipped</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="H">not shipped</mm:Entry>
    </mm:Map>
        <mm:Map name="scCurrencyToWcCurency">
        <mm:Entry key="USD">USD</mm:Entry>
    </mm:Map>
</mm:ValueMaps>
```

**

- getPageRequest

**

```
<out:Page   GeneratedOn="2014-06-19T16:30:15-04:00" IsFirstPage="Y" IsLastPage="Y" IsValidPage="Y" PageNumber="1" PageSize="30" xmlns:out="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/YCP/getPage/output">
    <out:Output>
    <out:OrderList      LastOrderHeaderKey="7289297001" LastRecordSet="Y" ReadFromHistory="N" TotalOrderList="7">
        <out:Order      MaxOrderStatus="3700" MaxOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MinOrderStatus="3700" MinOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MultipleStatusesExist="N" OrderDate="2013-11-19T10:23:56-05:00" OrderHeaderKey="201311191026091646239229" OrderNo="20019358516" Status="Shipped">
    <out:PriceInfo      Currency="USD" EnterpriseCurrency="USD" HeaderTax="0.00" ReportingConversionDate="2013-11-19T10:26:09-05:00" ReportingConversionRate="0.00" TotalAmount="113.42"/>
    <out:PersonInfoShipTo   AddressLine1="4872 Strand Road" AddressLine2="" AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5="" AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper="" City="Westerville" Company="" Country="US" Createprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Createts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Createuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="1000001521" Department="" EMailID="nouser1521@example.com" ErrorTxt="" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="Jon" HttpUrl="" JobTitle="" LastName="Fitch1521" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Modifyts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Modifyuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" OtherPhone="" PersonID="" PersonInfoKey="201310111545071262322239" PreferredShipAddress="" ShortZipCode="43081" State="OH" Suffix="" Title="" UseCount="0" VerificationStatus="" ZipCode="43081" isHistory="N"/>
    <out:OverallTotals      GrandCharges="10.00" GrandDiscount="0.00" GrandShippingBaseCharge="0.00" GrandShippingCharges="0.00" GrandShippingDiscount="0.00" GrandShippingTotal="0.00" GrandTax="7.42" GrandTotal="113.42" HdrCharges="0.00" HdrDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingBaseCharge="0.00" HdrShippingCharges="0.00" HdrShippingDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingTotal="0.00" HdrTax="0.00" HdrTotal="0.00" LineSubTotal="96.00" ManualDiscountPercentage="0.00" PercentProfitMargin="100.00"/>
    </out:Order>
    <out:Order      MaxOrderStatus="3700" MaxOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MinOrderStatus="3700" MinOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MultipleStatusesExist="N" OrderDate="2013-12-10T09:32:04-05:00" OrderHeaderKey="201312100933011987586483" OrderNo="20020096797" Status="Shipped">
    <out:PriceInfo      Currency="USD" EnterpriseCurrency="USD" HeaderTax="0.00" ReportingConversionDate="2013-12-10T09:33:01-05:00" ReportingConversionRate="0.00" TotalAmount="78.11"/>
    <out:PersonInfoShipTo   AddressLine1="4872 Strand Road" AddressLine2="" AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5="" AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper="" City="Westerville" Company="" Country="US" Createprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Createts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Createuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="1000001521" Department="" EMailID="nouser1521@example.com" ErrorTxt="" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="Jon" HttpUrl="" JobTitle="" LastName="Fitch1521" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Modifyts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Modifyuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" OtherPhone="" PersonID="" PersonInfoKey="201310111545071262322239" PreferredShipAddress="" ShortZipCode="43081" State="OH" Suffix="" Title="" UseCount="0" VerificationStatus="" ZipCode="43081" isHistory="N"/>
    <out:OverallTotals      GrandCharges="10.00" GrandDiscount="10.00" GrandShippingBaseCharge="0.00" GrandShippingCharges="0.00" GrandShippingDiscount="0.00" GrandShippingTotal="0.00" GrandTax="5.11" GrandTotal="78.11" HdrCharges="0.00" HdrDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingBaseCharge="0.00" HdrShippingCharges="0.00" HdrShippingDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingTotal="0.00" HdrTax="0.00" HdrTotal="0.00" LineSubTotal="73.00" ManualDiscountPercentage="0.00" PercentProfitMargin="100.00"/>
    </out:Order>
    <out:Order      MaxOrderStatus="3700" MaxOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MinOrderStatus="3700" MinOrderStatusDesc="Shipped" MultipleStatusesExist="N" OrderDate="2013-12-16T09:36:56-05:00" OrderHeaderKey="201312160938002091967609" OrderNo="20023794266" Status="Shipped">
    <out:PriceInfo      Currency="USD" EnterpriseCurrency="USD" HeaderTax="0.00" ReportingConversionDate="2013-12-16T09:38:00-05:00" ReportingConversionRate="0.00" TotalAmount="159.43"/>
    <out:PersonInfoShipTo   AddressLine1="4872 Strand Road" AddressLine2="" AddressLine3="" AddressLine4="" AddressLine5="" AddressLine6="" AlternateEmailID="" Beeper="" City="Westerville" Company="" Country="US" Createprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Createts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Createuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" DayFaxNo="" DayPhone="1000001521" Department="" EMailID="nouser1521@example.com" ErrorTxt="" EveningFaxNo="" EveningPhone="" FirstName="Jon" HttpUrl="" JobTitle="" LastName="Fitch1521" Lockid="0" MiddleName="" MobilePhone="" Modifyprogid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" Modifyts="2013-10-11T15:45:07-04:00" Modifyuserid="ANFCreateOrderFromWCSIntegServer" OtherPhone="" PersonID="" PersonInfoKey="201310111545071262322239" PreferredShipAddress="" ShortZipCode="43081" State="OH" Suffix="" Title="" UseCount="0" VerificationStatus="" ZipCode="43081" isHistory="N"/>
    <out:OverallTotals      GrandCharges="15.00" GrandDiscount="15.00" GrandShippingBaseCharge="0.00" GrandShippingCharges="0.00" GrandShippingDiscount="0.00" GrandShippingTotal="0.00" GrandTax="10.43" GrandTotal="159.43" HdrCharges="0.00" HdrDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingBaseCharge="0.00" HdrShippingCharges="0.00" HdrShippingDiscount="0.00" HdrShippingTotal="0.00" HdrTax="0.00" HdrTotal="0.00" LineSubTotal="149.00" ManualDiscountPercentage="0.00" PercentProfitMargin="100.00"/>
    </out:Order>
    </out:OrderList>
    </out:Output>
    </out:Page>
```

Regards,
TJ

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning multiple lines of output, add a comma at the end of each line of output, except the last.

`if ($CountFirstName > 0) then
    <_ord:OrderItem>,
       <_ord:OrderItemShippingInfo>,
             <_ord:ShippingAddress>,
                  <_wcf:ContactName>,
                  <_wcf:FirstName>{$CountFirstName}</_wcf:FirstName>,
                  </_wcf:ContactName>,
              </_ord:ShippingAddress>,
        </_ord:OrderItemShippingInfo>,
    </_ord:OrderItem>
else
    </_ord:Order>`